# Axios asynchrone ajax request Vuejs not waiting for server response

Tags: ajax, vue.js, asynchronous, async-await, axios

I try to get a list from server based on some filters. But vuejs not waiting server response.

```
   <input type="text" name="oooo" @input="getUsers">

    ...

    methods: {
      getUsers: async function () {
        const response = await axios.post('/skills', { {"key": "toto"} } );
        this.list = response.data;
        console.log(response);
      }
    }
    ...
```

I get results in server logs. but vuejs is returning empty array.
What is wrong with my ajax request?
thanks

Answer (score -1):

You are using axios.post, instead of axios.get